# Symfony, How to write a correct test to check if someone is deleted?

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony4

In my symfony project there is a PersonController with a function that takes an ID as a parameter.
Based on that ID I have to delete the correct user. The function looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/person/delete", methods={"DELETE"}, name="deletePersonById")
 */
public function deletePersonById(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $id = $request->query->get("id");
    $statuscode = 200;
    try {
        $this->personModel->deletePersonById($id);
        $message = "Person with id:" . $id . " deleted";
    } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $exception) {
        $statuscode = 400;
        $message = $exception->getMessage();
    } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
        $statuscode = 500;
        $message = $exception->getMessage();
    }

    return new JsonResponse($message, $statuscode);
}
```

Is it possible for me to check the value of the return in the UnitTest? Currently I think it returns the value NULL so I did the following in my unitTest: (I'm not sure if this is the way to test it? maybe it returns a 201 status code to say it is succesfully deleted? Any tips or advice?)

```
/**
 * @dataProvider providerPersons()
 **/
public function testDeletePersonById_personIdInDatabase_Persons($id)
{
    $PersonModel = new PDOPersonModel($this->connection, $this->validator);
    $expectedPersonId = null;
    $actualPersonId = $PersonModel->deletePersonById(strval($id));

    $this->assertEquals($expectedPersonId, $actualPersonId);
}
```

Comment: When I write code that deletes something, I usually test it by inserting something, making sure that it is in there, then deleting it, and then making sure it cannot be found. But I also usually don't delete things and instead just "mark something as deleted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good start is to clearly define how the person model behaves. Since you wrote "Currently I think it returns the value NULL", there seems to be some room for improvement.

I don't know what your person model looks like, so I'm just making something up here:

- `create` should create a person and return its id
- `getById` should return the person with the given id. If there is no person with that id, it should throw a specific exception.
- `deleteById` should delete the person with the given id. If there is no person with that id, it should throw a specific exception.

Given this specification, you can easily write a test: After deleting a person you should get an exception when trying to retrieve it again.

The advantage over peeking into the database to verify that it was deleted is, that you can change the implementation and technology all you want, as along as it doesn't break the contract.

A test could look something like this:

```
final class PersonModelTestCase extends TestCase
{
    private PDOPersonModel $personModel;

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function a_person_can_be_found_by_its_id()
    {
        $person = new Person('Jane', 'Doe', 'jane@doe.test');

        $id = $this->personModel->create($person);

        self::assertEquals($person, $this->personModel->getById($id));
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function getById_should_throw_an_exception_if_there_is_no_person_with_the_given_id()
    {
        $invalidId = 'invalid-id';

        self::expectExceptionObject(PersonModelException::notFound($invalidId));

        $this->personModel->getById($invalidId);
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function after_deleting_a_person_it_can_not_be_found_anymore()
    {
        $id = $this->personModel->create(new Person('Jane', 'Doe', 'jane@doe.test'));

        $this->personModel->deleteById($id);

        self::expectExceptionObject(PersonModelException::notFound($id));
        $this->personModel->getById($id);
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function deleteById_should_throw_an_exception_if_there_is_no_person_with_the_given_id()
    {
        $invalidId = 'invalid-id';

        self::expectExceptionObject(PersonModelException::deletionFailed($invalidId));

        $this->personModel->deleteById($invalidId);
    }

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->personModel = new PDOPersonModel($this->connection, $this->validator);
    }
}
```

But what about the controller? Besides verifying that the json response contains the correct data, there are several approaches to check that the person was really deleted.

1. You could apply basically the same as above. If there is an action to delete a person, I bet there is also one to get one.
2. You could call the delete action and verify that you can not get the deleted person via the person model anymore.
3. You could switch the person model implementation with a mock for the tests.